# Persist Data files in docker container

Tags: docker, boot2docker

This should not be hard but I can't figure it out. I have a container running and used `-v /tester` in the docker run command. I then do `docker exec ti containername /bin/bash`. I then create a file called /tester/stayhere.txt with `vi /tester/stayhere.txt`. I then save the file and verify it's there. Then I do a docker commit and start up the new image and the stayhere.txt is missing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mount a volume inside a docker container with `-v` it's not considered part of container itself. That's why when you commit changes it's missing.

According to Docker documentations:

> A data volume is a specially-designated directory within one or more containers that bypasses the Union File System.

And:

> Volumes are initialized when a container is created. If the container’s base image contains data at the specified mount point, that existing data is copied into the new volume upon volume initialization.

What this means is, data volumes live outside of *Union Filesystem* and if you even delete that container data volume still persists:

> Data volumes are designed to persist data, independent of the container’s life cycle. Docker therefore never automatically delete volumes when you remove a container, nor will it “garbage collect” volumes that are no longer referenced by a container.

So they are not part of your docker commit command.

In order to achieve what you want you need to copy file within the same path in your image while it's **not mounted** as docker volume. You can use Dockerfile or directly launch a container and alter filesystem then commit.

Next time when you launch a container **with volume** and you should be able to see those files.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say, without exactly what commands you're running. I'd be guessing that you're not actually starting the 'new' image somehow. I think that would be because you're "starting" it with `docker exec` (which kicks off things in a running container) rather than `docker run`.

More generally though, I would suggest that it's bad practice to change-and-commit. What you should really be doing is anything that's part of the build of your thing, you should do at build time (with a `Dockerfile`).

Anything that's persistent state, you should mount into your container - either via a volume mount, or a storage container.

It's pretty easy to create one of these:

```
docker create -v /path/to/data --name my_storage_container base-image-name /bin/true
```

And then start your container from a clean build image:

```
docker run -it --volumes-from my_storage_container image /bin/bash
```

Files you save then should persist, no matter how much you mess around with the image.

Comment: Thanks Sobrique I don't think I've quite got what you are saying but I've simplified the problem to try and get an answer. Basically my situation is this I have docker running in AWS and docker running in the IBM cloud. The container that I have running in AWS I would like to export and run in the IBM cloud but no matter what I do I can't get the files to stay. How would you suggest I move the container and files over to the IBM cloud?

Comment: I've tried docker save,export,commit but I think what you are telling me is that maybe I should use docker cp to get the files out of the container and the mount them into the new container... this seems odd because then I have to move over a docker image and set of data. That breaks my understanding of containers ... why not put it all in a container and move it around?

Comment: I might be able to expand more if you can post a command history of exactly what your ran.

Comment: But you don't need to do anything at all to have data persist in a container. "docker commit" is about updating the _image_ that your container came from. It is my opinion that that's bad practice - if you need to change the _image_ you should rebuild it, because that makes updating and redeploying much easier. Treat the container as a disposable unit in much the same way as you would a 'bash' process. "save" stuff if you want to keep it.

Comment: Thanks Sobrique I think your answers helped to guide me to the right way of thinking about this problem... which led me to this link that really hit the point home for me [http://container42.com/2013/12/16/persistent-volumes-with-docker-container-as-volume-pattern/] (http://container42.com/2013/12/16/persistent-volumes-with-docker-container-as-volume-pattern/)

Comment: This is also a great resource... wish I had found this when I first asked the question .. http://blog.giantswarm.io/moving-docker-container-images-around/